# Why is there an attribute error: int object has no attribute 'isnumeric'?

Tags: python, attributeerror, isnumeric

I am currently creating a program which will ask the user to enter a year and then states whether it is a leap year or not by seeing if the year is divisible by 4. It also has a type check, presence check and a length check. I keep on getting the AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

All in all, the program works well as I want it to (code below) but when the program has finished it states the aforementioned attribute error. Why does it display that message and how can I solve it?
Code:

```
print("Did you know that the last leap year was in 2020?")
print("To find out if a year is a leap year, use this program")
year = input("Please enter a year\n")
year = str(year)
valid = False

while valid == False:
  if year == "":
    print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
    year = input("Please enter a year\n")
    year = year.decode(year)
    valid == False
  else:
    if year.isnumeric() == False:
      print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
      year = input("Please enter a year\n")
      year = str(year)
      valid == False
    else: 
      if len(year) != 4: 
        print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
        year = input("Please enter a year\n")
        year = str(year)
        valid == False
      else:
        year = int(year)
        rem = year%4
        if rem == 0:
           print(f"{year} is a leap year")
        else: 
           print(f"{year} is not a leap year, unfortunately")
           valid == True
```

Comment: Not every year that's divisible by 4 is a leap year; 1900 was not a leap year, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You set `year` to an `int` here:

```
      else:
        year = int(year)
```

and then the `while` loop continues with code that assumes `year` is still a `str`, including this line:

```
  else:
    if year.isnumeric() == False:
```

Note that `isnumeric` is a method on `str` objects that tells you whether they contain at least one character and consist of only characters with Unicode properties Numeric_Type=Digit, Numeric_Type=Decimal, or Numeric_Type=Numeric. It is not a test for whether an object is a number, or whether a string represents a number - for example, `'-1'` and `'1.5'` report `False` for `isnumeric`.  `int` objects are not strings, so they have no such method.

To avoid this problem, I'd suggest separating the part of the code that gets a valid `year` (as an `int`) from the part of the code that figures out whether it's a leap year:

```
print("Did you know that the last leap year was in 2020?")
print("To find out if a year is a leap year, use this program")

# First get the year.
while True:
    try:
        year = int(input("Please enter a year\n"))
        if len(str(year)) != 4:
           raise ValueError("wrong number of digits!")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")

# year is now an int with 4 digits.  Now figure out if it's leap.
if year % 4 == 0:
    print(f"{year} is a leap year")
    # Note: there is a bug here, leap year calculation
    # is actually more complicated than this!
else: 
    print(f"{year} is not a leap year, unfortunately")
```

Some general notes on the "get a valid int" loop and how to do this kind of thing more simply than what you tried initially:

1. No need to convert the result of `input()` to a str or `decode` it.  `input` only ever returns a `str` (in modern versions of Python -- I see you lurking there, pedants).
2. Instead of trying to *predict* all the reasons that you might fail  to convert a string to an `int` and writing a bunch of `if`s to prevent them, just `try` the conversion and use an `except` to catch the `ValueError` that's raised on a failure.  That way you only have to write one error check, and you don't need to do it by trying to reverse-engineer what some other function will do before it does it.
3. Once you've already written a `try/except`, you can use a `raise` in the body of your `try` to automatically jump to the corresponding `except` instead of having to write the same error handling code twice.

Comment: This is why, once you have a value in a variable, you don't use the same name for the variable if you convert it to a different type. Use a different name and this problem can never happen.

Comment: @kindall what I wouldn't give for a `const` in Python.

Comment: Using `mypy` is also a good way to avoid this, since it'll infer a type when you first assign a variable and then complain if you assign a different type to it.